# Algoritmo Juego Pseint

Tags: algoritmos, pseint

Me encuentro realizando un juego con fines académicos.
El cual consiste en dos jugadores donde el principal objetivo del juego es reducir la vida del oponente a 0 para así determinar al ganador.

El juego consta de turnos donde cada oponente tendrá una cantidad de 100pts. para comenzar. Cada oponente tendrá como opción: atacar o bloquear al otro jugador en cada ataque. Si el jugador elige atacar al oponente y este no tiene activo el bloqueo, el ataque sera efectivo y se le descontara 10pts de vida al adversario.

Por otro lado, si elige bloquear, tendrá un 50% de probabilidad de que el siguiente ataque del oponente no le cause daño, si el ataque es bloqueado Cada ataque recibido o bloqueado, contara en 1 para llenar un indicador de ataque especial, si el contador de ataque especial es de 5 o más, en el turno correspondiente, a las opciones ya vistas se agregará “3.- Ataque especial, 4.- Recuperación”. Si el jugador realiza un ataque especial, este no podrá ser bloqueado y descontará 30 puntos de vida del jugador. Si el jugador realiza una recuperación, su vida actual aumentará en 10 puntos, no podrá eso si superar los 100 puntos de vida iniciales.

Al final de cada turno, el juego indicara la vida del jugador que recibió el ataque, si uno de los dos jugadores tiene 0 o menos puntos de vida, el juego indicara “El jugador xx, es el ganador.

Lo que llevo del algoritmo es lo siguiente:

```
Proceso sin_titulo
dimension jugador[2];
definir opc como numero;
definir jugador como caracter;
definir i Como Caracter;
definir j como caracter;
para i<-1 hasta 2 con paso 1 hacer 
    escribir " ingrese el nombre del jugador 1:";
    leer jugador[1];
    i<-jugador[1];
    escribir "seleccione la opcion ",jugador[1];
    Escribir " opcion 1 atacar ";
    escribir " opcion 2 bloquear ";
    escribir " opcion 3 ataque especial ";
    escribir " opcion 4 recuperacion ";
    leer opc;
    si opc = 1 entonces 
        escribir " usted eligio atacar al oponente";
    FinSi
    si opc = 2 entonces 
        escribir " usted ha elegido bloquear";
    FinSi
    escribir"";
    para j<-2 hasta 2 con paso 1 hacer 
     escribir " ingrese el nombre del jugador 2:";
      leer jugador[2];
      j<-jugador[2];
      escribir "seleccione la opcion";
      Escribir " opcion 1 atacar ";
      escribir " opcion 2 bloquear ";
      escribir " opcion 3 ataque especial ";
      escribir " opcion 4 recuperacion ";
      leer opc;
      si opc = 1 entonces 
        escribir " usted eligio atacar al oponente";
      FinSi
      si opc = 2 entonces 
        escribir " usted ha elegido bloquear";
     FinSi
    finpara
finpara
```

Comment: faltaría que desarrolles: la "salud" de cada jugador, el ciclo de "turnos" y como reducen la "salud" los diferentes "ataques"

Comment: Muchas Gracias! , entiendo un poco el concepto de lo que me faltaría. Solo que tengo la duda si seguir utilizando "PARA" o "SINO" para el "turno" de cada jugador y la "Salud" ya que lo utilice pero me arroja error , quizás no supe como hacerlo.

Comment: "mientras" hayan dos en pie ("con salud") que se den rosca "turnos"

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?